# How to exclude some users when broadcast?

Tags: phoenix-framework

As `broadcast!` will send message to all users subscribed to topic except sender, is it possible to except certain users? or send to a specific user?

I need users to push events to a channel, but only admin user will receive messages, other users will not receive messages, but only send them.

I can solve this at client side by simply let users ignore messages they receive via `broadcast!` and only admin user process received messages, but how to solve this at server side?

In short, join a channel, but can read only, or send only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store the user on the socket as explained in https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Token.html

```
defmodule MyApp.UserSocket do
  use Phoenix.Socket

  def connect(%{"token" => token}, socket) do
    case Phoenix.Token.verify(socket, "user", token, max_age: 1209600) do
      {:ok, user_id} ->
        socket = assign(socket, :user, Repo.get!(User, user_id))
        {:ok, socket}
      {:error, _} -> #...
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can check for the users admin status in the `handle_out` function for your channel [documented here](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Channel.html):

```
defmodule HelloPhoenix.RoomChannel do
  intercept ["new_msg"]
  ...
  def handle_out("new_msg", payload, socket) do
    if socket.assigns.user.admin do
      push socket, "new_msg", payload
    end
    {:noreply, socket}
  end
end
```

Depending on your volume of messages and number of admins, you may consider having an admin-specific channel for these events. This would prevent messages being sent to processes for non-admin users instead of simply ignoring them.

Comment: even if I dedicate a channel for admin, other users will join to it to send their messages to admin, then I will have to ignore non admin users at handle_out.. So its the same.. right?

Comment: You can have a channel that only the admins join. A message can be broadcast regardless of how it is sent. So you would keep the existing channel, and then broadcast to the admin channel from there using MyApp.Endpoint.broadcast. https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Endpoint.html

Comment: Thanks, that's what exactly I needed, to push a message without socket context.

Comment: why didn't you use handle_in in your answer? instead, you've used handle_out, why?

Comment: `handle_in` is for messages being sent to the channel. `handle_out` is called for each connected client, allowing you to ignore messages. You would still use `handle_in` for receiving the messags.

Comment: is handle_out always used with intercept?

Comment: `handle_out` is always called before a message is sent to the client via the websocket. You can read more at https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Channel.html

Comment: Thanks, but it's confusing me when to use push or broadcast?

Comment: You can use either `Phoenix.Channel.broadcast` (from inside of a channel module) or `MyApp.Endpoint.broadcast` (from anywhere else) to broadcast a message. This will call the `handle_out` callback for each connected process. You can then use `push` to send a message down the web socket.

Comment: so it's most likely that push can change the world around us, while broadcast works closer to the server side..