# Phoenix / Elixir: How do I send an event to just one client?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

There are three clients (A, B, C).

I need A to push a message that only B responds to.

```
channel.push("call", { "device_id": clientBdeviceId });
```

Is there a scalable way to only send a message to B and not to all clients?

Comment: You could have B listen to it's own topic. Something like `message:user_id`. That way, only B would get the message, because it wouldn't be sent to other users.

Comment: oooo how would I be able to push a message to this topic from A?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Phoenix channels: send push to a particular client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37680988/phoenix-channels-send-push-to-a-particular-client)